# Graphing functions with more than 2 variables (if possible)

Tags: functions

How do you graph a function that has more than $2$ variables (say, $4$ to $6$ variables)? I am only aware for a function that has $2$ variables but not for more than $2$, if it is indeed possible. If not possible, what can you recommend as I am trying to visualize such a function.

Also, any recommended software that generates the values of a function given the combinations of the values of the variables with a defined range (specifically, $4$ variables that takes $5$ possible values, so $625$ combinations)?

Thanks!

Comment: You may find [this selection of videos](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/thinking-about-multivariable-function) from Khan Academy helpful. It discusses a few of the most common ways to visualize multivariate functions

Comment: Will check. Thanks.